# APP Crashed after changing api 25 to 26 Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert to dimension: type=0x1

Tags: android, android-activity

I am getting the following exception, I tried a lot to fix it, but not to succeed, but now I found that, after updating my app from `API 25` to `API 26` now the app is directly crashing without opening activity. So app works well in lower version. but not in 26.

> logcat file.

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Cant convert to dimension: type=0x1
 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3320)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3416)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:229)
 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1821)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7410)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

Style.xml

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="alertDialogTheme">@style/AppCompatAlertDialogStyle</item>

</style>
<style name="AppCompatAlertDialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<!-- ToolBar -->
<style name="ToolBarStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Please share the activity code.

Comment: Even empty Activity with simple LinearLayout rooted xml. still crashed.

Comment: Please, share all your resource files (xml)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Just Convert

```
 compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
 compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
 compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
```

To this

```
 implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
 implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
 implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
```

and this

```
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
```

to only this

```
compileSdkVersion 26
```

Now its Working...